# SQL-Alchemy - Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc

I'm aware that this error already was posted multiple times on Stackoverflow, however I did not found anyone with the same situation as the following one.

With the following code I connected Python with SMSS

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
test_engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://DB_NAME')
opnames = pd.read_sql_table('view',test_engine,schema='input')
```

This worked untill yesterday. Then I suddenly got this error message:

*InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')*

It seems this has to do with connecting the engine? Reading through the internet I found that a 32-bit driver is needed for use with  a 32-bit application or a 64-bit driver for a 64-bit application.[image: ODBC source administrator]
My python runs on 32bit(just dropping any usefull info here)

```
import platform
platform.architecture
```

As far as I know SQL was not updated or anything, so it still is very unclear to me why the same code now raises this error message. Could anyone walk me through the process of troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: hey Stijn are there any login creds or is this a trusted connection? also, your screen shot isn't looking at the driver tab...try specifying driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server' in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you for the reaction. This is a trusted connection. I tried the following line: DWH_engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://ADB013?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server?trusted_connection=yes'). But it still not worked. Can this be a issue of specifying a Username and PW?

Comment: please also look at the drivers tab of the 'ODBC Data Source' in your screenshot. You may not want version 13 as you tried based on your comment if that option isn't available. the 32 v 64 bit is something I've run into with VBA but never in an ODBC connection using python as a side.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Suddenly I get this error when running even though it all used to work.  The database connection does work when the program is run as an admin on the (windows) machine.  So I vaguely suspect some kind of windows update issue.  No solution yet.